# Promise from browser.runtime.sendMessage() fulfilling prior to asynchronous call to sendResponse()

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have made a Firefox WebExtension that interacts with an executable (using [`runtime.connectNative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/connectNative)).

Here is the manifest of the extension:

```
// manifest.json file

{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "short_name": "myext",
  "version": "2.7",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background-script.js"],
    "persistent": true
    },
    "externally_connectable": {
      "ids": ["*"],
      "http://localhost/*"]
  },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "myext@myext.mysite.com",
      "strict_min_version": "50.0.0"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png",
    "32": "icon-32.png",
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
       "nativeMessaging",
       "webRequest"
    ]
}
```

Here is the content script:

```
// content-script.js

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.source == window &&
      event.data.direction &&
      event.data.direction == "from-page-script") {
    alert("Content script received message: \"" + JSON.stringify(event.data.message) + "\"");

    var sending = browser.runtime.sendMessage(event.data.message);

    sending.then(handleResponse, handleError);

  }
});

function handleResponse(message) 
{
  console.log("content-script : handleResponse : message = " + JSON.stringify(message));
  window.wrappedJSObject.foo.p = "OK : " + JSON.stringify(message);
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log("Message from the background script : " + error.message);
  window.wrappedJSObject.foo.p = "error";
}
```

And here is my background script:

```
// background-script.js

var port;

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{
    port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");
    var result = port.postMessage(request);

    port.onMessage.addListener(function(response)
    {
        console.log("Received: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        sendResponse(response);
    });
});
```

I have a problem regarding the following line in the background script:

```
sendResponse(response);
```

The method `handleResponse()` of the content script is called before the `sendResponse()` of the background script.

So, when the executable takes a longer time to do an action, the result of the executable is not sent to the content script, and the content script receives an undefined result.

Is there another way to send the result of the executable from the background script to the content script? Or use the callback another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is causing some confusion here.  Your `handleResponse()` is being called with the Promise fulfilled with *no arguments* because you exit the background script's `runtime.onMessage` listener without calling `sendResponse()`.  If `sendResponse()` had been called, then the argument would be the message<sup>1</sup>. Thus, you will need to adjust your `.then()` to differentiate between receiving no arguments (`sendResponse()` not called) and an argument containing the response message (`sendResponse()` called). If I recall correctly, if you were using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`, your `responseCallback` function would not be called unless `sendResponse()` is called.

[MDN describes the Promise as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage#Return_value):

> If the sender sent a response, this will be fulfilled with the response as a JSON object. Otherwise it will be fulfilled with no arguments. If an error occurs while connecting to the extension, the promise will be rejected with an error message.

### To call `sendResponse()` asynchronously, you need to `return true;` from your `runtime.onMessage` listener

You are calling `sendResponse()` from within an asynchronous callback.  As a result, you exit the `runtime.onMessage` listener prior to `sendResponse()` being called.  If you are going to do that, and still want to call `sendResponse()`, you need to return `true` from your `runtime.onMessage` listener.

From [MDN `runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage) regarding `sendResponse()`:

> This function returns a `boolean`. It should return `true` from the event listener if you wish to call `sendResponse` after the event listener returns.

So your code could be:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{
    port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");
    var result = port.postMessage(request);

    port.onMessage.addListener(function portOnMessageListener(response)
    {
        //sendResponse is only valid once. So, if this is how you want to use it, you need
        //  to remove the listener, or in some other way not call sendResponse twice.
        port.onMessage.removeListener(portOnMessageListener);
        console.log("Received: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        sendResponse(response);
    });
    return true;
});
```

### `sendResponse()` is valid only once

The `sendResponse()` function is valid for only one message (i.e. you get to send only one response per message sent).  If your desire is to send multiple messages to the content script, you will need to set up doing so in a different way.

---

1. The [MDN docs state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage#Return_value) the message is a "JSON object". What they probably mean that it is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) that was converted from JSON, which was used to represent it while the message was in transit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and exhaustive answer

Comment: @Thordax, I'm glad that I was able to help. If you are going to get multiple messages from your `port`, there are multiple methods which could be used. However, it did not really look like you were expecting more than one message on your port. If it was me, just for testing, after removing the primary listener, I would probably add another one that logs an error or warning if something else comes through. In development, that would allow you to see that something else was sent, even though you are not expecting anything. Alternately, you could disconnect the port.